# SVG image cover regardless of size/orientation

Tags: svg

Expect the embedded snippet below to generate a screen like the picture on Firefox, etc.  The two unclipped images are shown at the bottom for reference - one landscape and one portrait.  Above are four demo shapes that I want to be covered by the images without really knowing anything about the image - ideally I could replace just the URLs and get all "correct" images and avoiding any math or conditions.

The patterns and images should be identical, not matched to the demo scenarios. Ultimately I need just ONE such shape in an svg template satisfying any one injected image.

I think I definitely want `xMidYMid` for both pattern and image.  I've tried many permutations of viewBox, heights, widths, `slice`/`meet`, patternContentUnits, and patternUnits attributes.

I can't even really figure out what the "wrong" images are being scaled to.  It seems like the two demos of each image are exactly the same scale (because the demo rects are all 490 in the long direction, and it's as though the short side of the image is being matched to the long side of the rect or something??)

[image]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 1020 1220" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <pattern
       id="patternA"
       height="1"
       width="1"
       viewBox="0 0 1 1"
       patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"
       preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
        <image
            id="imageA"
            width="1" height="1"
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
            transform=""
            xlink:href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1625507371147-797709a083a6?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=334&amp;q=80" />
    </pattern>
    <pattern
       id="patternB"
       height="1"
       width="1"
       viewBox="0 0 1 1"
       patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"
       preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
        <image
            id="imageB"
            width="1" height="1"
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
            transform=""
            xlink:href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1625508200971-f63b282addb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1189&amp;q=80" />
    </pattern>
    <pattern
       id="patternC"
       height="1"
       width="1"
       viewBox="0 0 1 1"
       patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"
       preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <image
            id="imageC"
            width="1" height="1"
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
            transform=""
            xlink:href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1625507371147-797709a083a6?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=334&amp;q=80" />
    </pattern>
    <pattern
       id="patternD"
       height="1"
       width="1"
       viewBox="0 0 1 1"
       patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"
       preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <image
            id="imageD"
            width="1" height="1"
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
            transform=""
            xlink:href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1625508200971-f63b282addb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1189&amp;q=80" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect
     style="fill:url(#patternA);stroke:black;"
     x="10"
     y="10"
     width="490"
     height="200" />
  <rect
     style="fill:url(#patternB);stroke:blue;"
     x="510"
     y="10"
     width="500"
     height="200" />
  <rect
     style="fill:url(#patternA);stroke:red;"
     x="160"
     y="220"
     width="200"
     height="490" />
  <rect
     style="fill:url(#patternB);stroke:green;"
     x="670"
     y="220"
     width="200"
     height="490" />
  <rect
     style="fill:url(#patternC);stroke:black;"
     x="10"
     y="720"
     width="490"
     height="490" />
  <rect
     style="fill:url(#patternD);stroke:black;"
     x="510"
     y="720"
     width="490"
     height="490" />
</svg>
```

Instead, the "wrong" demos should cover like this, with the image basically starting at 0x0 in the center and scaling up only until the image exactly covers the rectangle, but no further:

[image]

There are similar questions here on SO that I've already used in getting this far.

Comment: And you must use a pattern right? It's gonna be used over non rectangular shapes?

Comment: yes, it will be used on an arbitrary path by its bounding box - I assumed that the answer will be easy to apply, but that rects would be simpler to ask about.

Comment: Sure, just confirming that going back to a simple <image> case isn't a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

What you want can't be done I don't think.  In order for the image to be scaled correctly to the shape using `meet` or `slice`, the size of the image needs to be known.

In your initial attempts, there is nothing there that gives the renderer any idea what the actual dimensions of the images are.  Or even what their aspect ratios are.

**For example**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 1020 1220" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>

    <pattern
       id="patternA"
       height="1"
       width="1"
       viewBox="0 0 3977 5965"
       patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"
       preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
        <image
            id="imageA"
            width="3977" height="5965"
            xlink:href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1625507371147-797709a083a6?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=334&amp;q=80" />
    </pattern>
    
    <pattern
       id="patternB"
       height="1"
       width="1"
       viewBox="0 0 3941 2217"
       patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"
       preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
        <image
            id="imageB"
            width="3941" height="2217"
            xlink:href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1625508200971-f63b282addb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1189&amp;q=80" />
    </pattern>
    
  </defs>
  <rect
     style="fill:url(#patternA);stroke:black;"
     x="10"
     y="10"
     width="490"
     height="200" />
  <rect
     style="fill:url(#patternB);stroke:blue;"
     x="510"
     y="10"
     width="500"
     height="200" />
  <rect
     style="fill:url(#patternA);stroke:red;"
     x="160"
     y="220"
     width="200"
     height="490" />
  <rect
     style="fill:url(#patternB);stroke:green;"
     x="670"
     y="220"
     width="200"
     height="490" />
  <rect
     style="fill:url(#patternA);stroke:black;"
     x="10"
     y="720"
     width="490"
     height="490" />
  <rect
     style="fill:url(#patternB);stroke:black;"
     x="510"
     y="720"
     width="490"
     height="490" />
</svg>
```

Comment: "the size of the image needs to be known" the browser certainly knows it, otherwise how would the  `preserveAspectRatio` work on the <image>? The thing here is that the target element's size should get passed down to the <image> through the <pattern>, and I'm not sure it can be done...

Comment: I meant that if the OP uses preserveAspectRatio on the image, then information about the original bounds of the image are lost, and they won't get the correct/desired result in the pattern.  That's because the image is effectively "a 1x1 square with an image somewhere within it" at that point.

Comment: But why is it a 1x1 square rather than the 490x200 rect the pattern is supposed to define now? They did set the patternContentUnits to map to the target element (well they actually did it with viewBox, but it ends to be the same either ways), so in my understanding width="1"  should be the full width of the target element (490 units) and height="1" should be the full height (200 unicorns). What makes the size propagation stops somewhere in the middle?

Comment: Thanks. If I set a rect's pattern's image's height and width and the rect's pattern's viewBox all to values matching the aspect ratio of the rect, then I get the desired behavior.  This is suboptimal because it means pre-computing the bounding box of my target, but it could work in my case.  So far you've helped me see that the 1x1 square of the image is effectively clipping it to a covering square, then the pattern is scaling that square up to cover the rect, explaining the scaling effect that I didn't like.

Comment: @Kaiido Because the `width` and `height` are both specified. So the image will be scaled and positioned in the 1x1 square based on the `preserveAspectRatio` setting.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Which width and height are you talking about? If the ones of the <image>, why is 1 unicorn x 1 unicorn a square when they should represent the ratio of the target width and the ratio of the target height respectively? Once again, why does the size propagation stops in the middle?

Comment: @Kaiido The image element will end up being a 1x1 square, with the image placed somewhere within that (assuming `meet`), or will occupy the whole square (if `slice` - as in OP's case). See https://jsfiddle.net/8g6q7ufb/1/

Comment: But **why is it a square**? With `objectBoundingBox` the unit is supposed to be relative to the target's size, so 1 is like CSS 100% if you will. So why in the context of a non squared target 1x1 (a.k.a 100% x 100%) is a square?

Comment: @Kaiido Why is what a square? The `<image>` element ends up a square because its `width` and `height` are both 1. The pattern is a square for the same reason. Although it may not appear to be because it is applied to a non-square target.  Incidentally, the `patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"` has no effect ([see here for why](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/pservers.html#PatternElementPatternContentUnitsAttribute)).

Comment: But with the viewBox set to `0 0 1 1` you have the same thing as `patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"` and even if you do remove the `viewBox` and use `patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"` you'd get the same result. So once again... why are `width="1"` and `height="1"` equal to the same number of `px` at the end. These values are supposed to represent  the ratio of the target's width and height respectively. `1` for `width` is not supposed to be the same number of `px` as `1` for height. They are supposed to be relative. So 1x1 is not supposed to be a square.

Comment: @Kaiido The pattern viewBox describes how the pattern contents fit into the 1x1 (width x height) pattern.  It doesn't have anything to do with the target rect.

Comment: ...it has everything to do with the target rect. The `patternUnits` is `objectBoundingBox`, the pattern's `width="1"` and `height="1"` represent the target's width and height (this works as expected). Then, when the viewBox is set to `0 0 1 1` it will set the coordinate system inside the pattern to map to this pattern size, and since this pattern's size has been set to the target's size, the coordinate system inside the pattern *should* map directly to the target's rect too, this fails. But anyway, and for the third time, just remove that viewBox, you'll get the same results, why?